# JavaScript tasks

Tags: javascript

I have been learning JavaScript and I have been doing some tasks, which I got in my college.
Tasks go like this:

> Make a webpage, where 3 200x150 images and one 600x450 image will appear. Add JavaScript function, which will make sure, that the 600x450 image shown will be an enlarged image of an 200x150 image, on which we have pointed with a mouse previously (call the function with onMouseOver).

The second task goes like this:

> Complete the webpage from task 1 in a way, when clicking the smaller image, the bigger image of the same image, we clicked will appear in a new window.

The code for the 1st task looks like this:

```
function bigImg(x)    
{
    x.style.height="600px";
    x.style.width="450px";
}

function normalImg(x)
{
    x.style.height="200px";
    x.style.width="150px";
}

...

<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="slika1.jpg" alt="slika1" width="150" height="200">
<img src="slika2.jpg">
<img src="slika3.jpg">
```

For the 2nd one like this:

```
function swipe() 
{
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('Slika1');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.style.width=450+"px";

    // enter code here

    var url=largeImage.getAttribute('src');
    window.open(url,'Image','width=largeImage.style.width,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1');
}

...

<img src="slika1.jpg" id= "Slika1" onClick="swipe();"/>
<img src="slika2.jpg">
<img src="slika3.jpg">
```

What should be done differently?

Comment: So... what's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: The problem is in the task 2, where the larger image DOESN'T appear, so I need help.

Comment: Then maybe you should put that in your question? How would we automatically know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function swipe(image) 
{
    newWidth=450+"px";
    newHeight=600+"px";

    var url=image.getAttribute('src');
    myWindow=window.open('','Image','width='+newWidth+',height='+newHeight+',resizable=1');
    myWindow.document.write('<img src="'+url+'" width="'+newWidth+'" height="'+newHeight+'" />');
}
</script>

<img src="slika1.jpg" onClick="swipe(this);"/>
<img src="slika2.jpg" onClick="swipe(this);"/>
<img src="slika3.jpg" onClick="swipe(this);"/>
```

To answer a few questions of the original poster:

The first parameter in the window.open() function here is '' (empty string), which basically creates a blank web page. The return value of this function call is the newly opened web page (which is assigned to the variable myWindow). You then drill down into that window object and call it's document.write() function to actually display the desired HTML (the image). In your original code you were simply opening a window that browsed to the image file (not an HTML page). Since that was the case, there is no way you could have actually set the width or height of the image--you were just setting (or trying to) the width and height of the window.  Setting the width and height of the window wasn't even working in your example code because you didn't break the variable out of the string.  So in the window.open() function you needed to pass a string in the third parameter that looked like:

> width=450px,height=600px,resize=1

But what you were actually passing was:

> width=largeImage.style.width,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1

The swipe() function we created takes in a single parameter "image".  When we call this function from the onClick event inside the img tag we use the keyword "this" to pass a reference of itself.  Essentially a copy of the img object that called swipe() is passed in as a parameter.  So in the function, image.getAttribute('src') references the "src" attribute of the img object that called it, which you need to display in the opened window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Gremio! That really helped!
I have one question: why is myWindow.document.write very important in this case? And what does image.getAttribute do?

Comment: No problem.  I edited the original answer (there was too much to include in a simple comment) to try and address your questions.